# Why does Ruby module inclusion exclude the module's singleton class?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module, singleton, mixins

When classes are inherited in Ruby the singleton classes are also inherited:

```
class A
  def self.hello
    puts "hello"
  end
end

class B < A
end

B.hello #=> "hello"
```

Yet with modules, this is not the case:

```
module M
  def self.goodbye
    puts "goodbye"
  end
end

class A
  include M
end

A.goodbye #=> NameError
```

To get around this limitation many ppl resort to this ugly hack:

```
module M
  def self.included(c)
    c.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def goodbye
      puts "goodbye"
    end
  end
end
```

Ok, so my question: is there a theoretical/conceptual reason behind this limitation on modules? or was it just an implementation difficulty?

After looking at the C source code (YARV/MRI) I can identify there is an implementation difficulty (not insurmountable, but one all the same), but is this the sole reason? Are there any other reasons for this limitation?

thanks

Comment: Why should they? Including a module is not the same thing as inheriting a class.

Comment: @Mladen, I don't buy this. If the conceptual distinction was so clear then why do people (even very top Ruby programmers) try to get around this limitation by using the `ClassMethods` hack? Further -- why is it so impt that somehow the nature of module implies *this* particular limitation.

Comment: IMHO, module mixins != multiple inheritance, so whatever some people might be doing doesn't really prove anything. BTW, can you illustrate the need for the hack by a real-world example, where one couldn't, for example, achieve the same by including module `A` and extending by module `B`?

Comment: @Mladen, your example is precisely where the hack comes in handy...you no longer _need_ to `include A` and `extend B` as including `A` is sufficient. Also simply saying 'they're different' without giving any explanation is weak. My question was what is the theory behind such a difference....or is there no theory at all and it was simply an implementation difficulty ? Looking at the source I am lead to believe it's just an implementation difficulty.

Comment: Please note that I'm not saying that your expectation is wrong. Simply, `include` is clearly defined in docs as nothing but invoking `append_features` on a module, which in turn means, _adding the constants, methods, and module variables of the module_. It doesn't stand in for inheritance.

Comment: @Mladen....i understand that `include` performs as is stated in the docs...but aside from simply accepting that 'it just does this because that's what the docs say, so that's what it does. Full stop.' im actually curious if the REAL reason it doesn't do more..is because of the implementation difficulties! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless anyone can come up with a compelling argument, i feel that the limitation is just down to implementation difficulty. Nonetheless i've been working on the problem the last couple of days and have (in beta) a new version of include called `include_complete` that gets around these difficulties and allows modules inheritance to work like class inheritance (bringing in the singleton)

Check out the project here: http://github.com/banister/include_complete

And beware the project is still very much in beta, but still seems to work as desired so far

Answer (score 0):

Warning: the following is just speculation.

If you're using a class, you'll need singleton class methods, because you rely on them to create the object (eg `MyClass.new`). If you're using a module, you don't need them, because you can't create objects purely from a module.

Comment: singleton methods can be used for much more than creating objects; i dont think this can be the reason, but thanks:)